# Attribute type checking is lost after wrapping React component with injectIntl()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-intl

Let's say I have a component `Card`, which looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface Props {
    title: string;
}

export class Card extends React.Component<Props, null> {
    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.title}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Now because of the props I have to use this component with the attribute `title`.

```
<Card title="Example" />
```

I need to wrap this component with `injectIntl()` from `react-intl`, so the `intl` context is injected. I do this like that:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {injectIntl} from 'react-intl';

interface Props {
    title: string;
}

class Component extends React.Component<Props, null> {
    // ..
}

export const Card = injectIntl(Component);
```

Now I can use the `Card` component without the attribute `title`.

```
<Card />
```

This seems to be just fine for the typescript compiler. There are also no runtime errors. I expected that the compiler throws an error like this:

```
Property 'title' is missing in type '{}'.
```

Where does this behavior come from? Why is it like this? How to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You need to install [@types/react-intl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-intl) package.

`react-intl` package doesn't use type annotations, as you can see in the source of [inject.js](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/blob/master/src/inject.js). Component returned by `injectIntl` is completely different component than your `Card`. Types from `@types/react-intl` package add the missing type annotations.

Comment: Thank you @Tomáš! Your answer pointed me into the right direction. Actually I didn't install the types, so typescript didn't know what to validate, while compiling. Maybe you can update your question with that hint?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-intl

Comment: @Robin Answer updated. Good catch! I forgot that Typescript has an external repository of type annotations.